# Как достать html код страницу на py через requests?

Tags: python, html5, requests

Собираюсь делать веб-парсер на *python*. Нужен способ получения html кода страницы через библиотеку ***requests***.

Comment: `rs.text` или `rs.content`, при `rs = requests.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1306432/")`

Comment: text ли не метод?

Comment: Спасибо, вот так у новичков бывает, целый день гуглишь проблему - в итоге, дело всего лишь в скобочках

Comment: Как отметить твой коммент ответом?

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад, что помог :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через поля [rs.text](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) (вернет как строку, тип `str`, в кодировке от сервера) или [rs.content](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) (вернет как массив байт, тип `bytes`), например:

```
rs = requests.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1306432/")
```

Но ответ можно получить по частям, например, это пригодится при скачивании большого файла, который может не влезть в память, тогда в запрос указывается параметр [`stream=True` и ответ возвращается через `rs.raw` или метод `iter_content`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content):

```
rs = requests.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1306432/", stream=True)

# print(rs.raw.read(10))

# Метод iter_content предпочтительнее
for chunk in rs.iter_content(1024):
    print(chunk)
```